# Why the dark objects won't be differenced from the base object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

[image: Gear2]

I made the objects by creating a cube in Object mode, going into Edit mode, deleting the vertices, clicking <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> new vertices, making a face and extruding.

On the light colored objects, I can add a Boolean modifier and set it to *Difference*, and it would make a hole in the base object the shape of the new object. However, inspite of these dark objects were made the same way as the lighter ones, when I try to apply a Boolean modifier, it deletes the base object.

Comment: In Edit Mode select all of your vertices and Recalculate the Normals. The option is in your Tool Tab in the Shading/UV's tab

Answer (score 1):

In Edit Mode select all of your vertices and Recalculate the Normals. The option is in your Tool Tab in the Shading/UV's tab (Press the "T" key to toggle the Tool Tab on/off).

[image]